# GRUB unable to detect Windows 10 using Boot-Repair

Tags: windows, grub2, kali-linux

I have been using Windows 8.1 and Kali Linux 3.14 for a while. But upgrading to Windows 10 resulted in installation of MBR instead of GRUB. As I usually do, I used the [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) Bootable USB to solve the issue. Boot-Repair has Successfully installed GRUB but it is not detecting Windows 10.

I tried the install GRUB manually:
`root@Zuhayer:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installation finished. No error reported.`

Error:

```
root@Zuhayer:/# update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.14-kali1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.14-kali1-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.12-kali1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.12-kali1-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7-trunk-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7-trunk-amd64
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda2
error: out of memory.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: line no: 179
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
```

Comment: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/37904?project=1&cat[0]=31&string=grub

Comment: please post the output of the following command:  `cat -n /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new`

Comment: @mchid Here is the link to the output of the file. http://pastebin.com/cMXbBFf6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened:

Following a article on how to fix my problem, I had added some code in the source file from which grub.cfg is generated at line no: 179.

When I removed that code the grub-update command worked correctly.

P.s. Thanks [mchid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70847/mchid) for the responses

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# fix broken grub.cfg gen
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

---

**EDIT:**

Change the contents of /etc/grub.d/41_custom to the following and then run update-grub:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF
if [ -f  \${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source \${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "\${config_directory}" -a -f  \$prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source \$prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
EOF
```

[source](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/38041?project=1&cat[0]=31&string=grub)

Comment: I have added the line at the end of /etc/default/grub, then updated the GRUB. Same Error.